# 2D array traversal coding problem C++/ recursive function not returning correct value

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I have been trying to solve a puzzle which asks whether it is possible for a king (in chess) to walk to a target square without passing through a square covered by a queen, given the input of the board size, the queen x and y, the king x and y and the target x and y. I have written a (very inefficient) recursive function to solve the problem, however, it is returning a negative number, so I am wondering where I made a mistake in the function, or elsewhere in the code. The code is in c++ and is as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long

int n;
int qx, qy;
int kx, ky;
int cx, cy;
vector<vector<int>> board;
vector<vector<bool>> visited;
vector<int> temp;
bool done;

void initboard(){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j ++){
            if(i == qy-1 || j == qx-1){
                temp.push_back(3);
            }
            else if(abs(i+1-qy) == abs(j+1-qx)){
                temp.push_back(3);
            }
            else if(i == ky-1 && j == kx-1){
                temp.push_back(0);
            }
            else if(i == cy-1 && j == cx-1){
                temp.push_back(1);
            }
            else{
                temp.push_back(2);
            }
        }
        board.insert(board.begin(),temp);
        temp = {};
    }
}

bool safe(int x, int y){
        return board[y][x]==2;
}

bool solve(int x, int y){
    if(!done){
        visited[y][x] = 1;
        if(board[y][x] == 3){
            return 0;
        }
        else if(y == cy-1 && x == cx-1){
            done = 1;
            return 1;
        }
        vector<vector<int>> tovisit = {{x+1,y}, {x-1,y}, {x,y+1}, {x,y-1},{x+1,y+1}, {x+1,y-1}, {x-1,y+1}, {x-1,y-1}};
        for(vector<int> next : tovisit){
            if(done) return 1;
            if(!visited[next[1]][next[0]] && next[0]>-1 && next[0]<n && next[1]>-1 && next[1]<n){
                solve(next[0],next[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return 1;

    }
}


int main(){
    cin>>n>>qx>>qy>>kx>>ky>>cx>>cy;
    initboard();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout<<board[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<solve(kx-1,ky-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you using to test (n, qx, qy, kx, ky, cx, cy)?

Comment: n = 8, qx = 4, qy = 4, kx = 1, ky = 3, cx = 3, cy = 1, If I remember correctly.

Comment: Have these `next[0]>-1 && next[0]<n && next[1]>-1 && next[1]<n` checks before this `!visited[next[1]][next[0]]` check.

Comment: Tried that just now and its still returning the same large negative number (from shell)-1073741819.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning a non-zero return code makes it seem like it's crashing somewhere. A good practice when writing homework code is to use `vector.at(i)` instead of `vector[i]` since the former will throw an exception when it's out of bounds (rather than just randomly accessing memory). When I did that I found the `visited` vector was empty and causing it to crash. I changed the `initboard()` method to also initialize the `visited` vector:

```
void initboard(){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        visited.emplace_back();
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j ++){
            visited.back().push_back(false);
            ...
```

and it doesn't crash anymore and prints something out (not sure how right this is):

```
2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 
3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 
2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
0 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 
2 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 
3 2 1 3 2 2 3 2 
1
```

Another tip would be make sure `solve()` always returns a value, right now it looks like it's possibly that it makes it to the end and doesn't return.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that looks like the correct output, I’ll try it out when I can.

Comment: This works for all the test cases except - "999
999 999
998 1
1 998"

Comment: What’s the expected output for that case?

Comment: 1 (after the array). But I’ve removed the printing of the array.